# The relationship between n^n and n! contains the $e$ number, why exactly?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was experimenting with factorials and $n^n$ powers in Python. I'm computing $n^n/n!$ for values of integer values of $n$ between 1 and 500.

```
import numpy as np

def func(i,j):
  arr = np.arange(i,j, dtype='object')
  pows = np.power(arr,arr)
  facts = np.array(list(map(np.math.factorial,arr)))
  division = np.divide(pows,facts)
  return (arr, pows, facts, division)

result = func(1,500)
for i in result:
  print(i)
```

This gives the output of $1^1/1! = 1$, $2^2/2! = 4/2 = 2$, and so on.

```
1.0
2.0
4.5
10.666666666666666
26.041666666666668
64.8
163.4013888888889
416.1015873015873
1067.6270089285715
2755.731922398589
7147.658895778219
18613.926233766233
48638.8461384701
...
```

I couldn't see any patterns there yet, and because the numbers are (not too suprisingly) rising exponentially, I decided to divide the 2nd result with the 1st, 3rd with 2nd and so on.

```
growth = [a/b for a,b in zip(result[1:], result[:-1])]
for i in growth:
  print(i)
```

And this time, the pattern was obvious.

```
2.0
2.25
2.3703703703703702
2.4414062500000004
2.48832
2.521626371742113
2.546499697040713
2.565784513950348
2.581174791713197
2.5937424601
2.604199011897531
.
.
.
2.7155466794960517
2.7155521726837963
2.715557643851069
```

It was obvious that the series were converging to $e$. But why might that be?

Comment: $n^n/n!$ is asymptotically equivalent to $e^n/\sqrt{2\pi n}\to\infty$. As written, the premise is incorrect. Perhaps your Python script is calculating something slightly different?

Comment: @FShrike, that is because the OP is then dividing $(n+1)$st result by previous $n$th result.

Comment: Ah I see. You are computing: $$\frac{\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{n^n}{n!}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\to e$$

Comment: Tunahan: my second comment shows (if you know the famous $(1+1/n)^n\to e$), with a little algebra, why the ratios converge to $e$. My first comment was maybe a bit mysterious: there *is* a link there, which I used, between $n^n,n!$, but it is a lot more difficult - it is called *Stirling’s approximation*. You might enjoy looking this one up, and there are proofs in a few places on this site.

Comment: If I compute $(1+1/500)^{500}$, I get an answer very similar to the OPs final result.  The convergence towards $e$ is just very slow.

Comment: @peterwhy To back up Doug’s comment, the first integer at which the sequence gets the first digits $2.718$ correct, according to my calculator, is the integer $4822$. $(1+1/4822)^{4822}=2.71800001954$ whereas $(1+1/4821)^{4821}=2.7179999611$. :)

Comment: If you use a Taylor series expansion, it should be straightforward to see that $e - (1+1/n)^n$ is asymptotic to $\frac{e}{2n}$.

Comment: In hindsight, I should have known how to simplify that, it just didn't click. Thank you all.

Comment: Yep, ironically $\sum (1+\frac1n)^n$ converges much, much more slowly than just $\sum 1/n!$

Comment: @Doug. A much better approximation is $(1+1/n)^{(n+1/2)}.$